# How to make edgy corners with css

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to make edgy corners like in the following below? See how the edge wraps around the corner. I would like to know the term as well (if any). cross browser support (IE8 and up, bonus IE7) is a must. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: It is easier to create this with a image probably.

Comment: And also, this is not a "give me this code" community. Sorry :(

Comment: Well im just not sure where to even start. Sorry if I upset anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-ribbons/). I don't know how crossbrowser compatible it is (as it is CSS3), but it achieves the effect you want.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

h2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px 10px 10px -70px;
    background-color: orange;
}

h2:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666 #666 transparent transparent;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2w8eU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{
    background: #666;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.ribbon{
    background: #FFA500;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    left: -20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.ribbon::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 16px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #FFA500 transparent transparent;    
    z-index: -5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
</div>
```

([DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/4974592))

I don't think IE 7/8 support the `::before` pseudo-element, so if you want IE compatibility add another element and put `::before` styles on it :)

Answer (score 0):

That `edgy corner` is only a `div` with a `triangle` actually, you only need **ONE** element to do it.

```
<div id="myCorner"></div>
```

**myCorner** will be the div, and **myCorner:after** will be the triangle.

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Xp6E7/2/

[image]

```
#myCorner
{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:orange;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px black;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px black;
    position:relative;

}

#myCorner:after
{
    content:"";    
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:100%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-color: orange orange transparent transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Here is a small improvement on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/DcWGY/1/. This is a reversed way to do, but when we are adding text to the h2 now, we have to specify on the `#myCorner:after { content: ""; }` and this is where the script loses its usability.

Comment: @Starx I updated the answer with your fix. I tried to make the `div` as the original element, and the `triangle` as the `:after` element, but I couldn't position the triangle UNDER (absolute) the div, I needed this to look good.

Comment: @Starx Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Xp6E7/ , `z-index` doesn't seem to work.